# Unwanted TitleBar on the main activity background of a cocos2d-x Android project

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I am working on a mobile game using the cocos2d-x framework. During the application launch, there is a 500-600ms freezing time on a black screen due to the first scene creation. I would like to display rather a basic splash screen during this time.

I first tried to follow [this example given by Chris Stewart](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/), but with no success since the freezing time occurs just after the main activity has been constructed. So the splash screen correctly appears at launch, but the freezing black screen still follows.

To achieve what I want, I now try to put the surface view on top of the window and to define a background (ie. the splash screen) for the main activity. The only way I found to achieve this is to use the [setZOrderOnTop](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html#setZOrderOnTop(boolean)) method.

The main activity overrides the [`Cocos2dxActivity::onCreateView()`](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/8b6a07feacb7252fefb97fdb432192fe636cbf0a/cocos/platform/android/java/src/org/cocos2dx/lib/Cocos2dxActivity.java#L408) in order to put the surface view on top of the window:

```
public class AppActivity extends Cocos2dxActivity {

    @Override
    public Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView onCreateView() {
        Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView glSurfaceView = super.onCreateView();
        glSurfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(true);

        return glSurfaceView;
    }

}
```

The `AndroidManifest.xml` is basically the same as the default one delivered with cocos2d-x, I only changed the theme to `@style/SplashTheme` which is defined below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="xxx"
    android:installLocation="auto">

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

        <!-- Tell Cocos2dxActivity the name of our .so -->
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                   android:value="xxx" />

        <activity
            android:name="xxx.AppActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Here is my `values/styles.xml`, it only contains the basic style mentioned above which is based on `Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen`:

```
<resources>

    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

And the `drawable/splash.xml` which sets a gray background and displays an icon on the center of the screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/gray"/>

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

This configuration seems to achieve what I want. The background defined above acts like a splash screen and is hidden then by the first scene after 500-600ms. **But** during the loading, an unwanted white bar appears on the top (see images below) and disappears once the first scene has been loaded.

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

After nearly a day trying to find the origin of this, I am looking for help.

- **What is the origin of this white bar ?**
- **Is there a better approach to achieve what I want ?**

Comment: Why not create the splash in the cocos2d-x code ? 
Advantages is more easy to do, it will work on all platforms here it will only work on Android. The goal here in cocos2d-x is just to have one Android Activity and that activity is cocos2d-x I think this not a good approach because cocos2d-x is multi platform

Comment: The freezing time is due to cocos2d-x loading. The problem is I want to customize this loading screen, not simply display a useless splash during a fixed period of time. If you run the hello world project on a not too recent smartphone, you will see that freezing time.